# Renaming links in firefox history due to domain name change

Tags: firefox

I have a lot of links in my history to sites I regularly use. Example:

https://foo.example.org/1234
https://foo.example.org/5678

Now the site moved. I'd like to be able to access all those sites through my address bar as I am used to. AFAIK that means I have to change the links in the history to ...

https://bar.example.org/1234
https://bar.example.org/5678

1. Is there a way to realize that?
2. Is there a way to realize it via a) firefox GUI, b) text editor, c) another tool?

Comment: the history is saved in a sqlite DB. so you could close FF and then update the DB with sql statements

Comment: Thanks. Is there a GUI based tool (add-on, whatever) to do that (question 2)?

Comment: that would be asking for a recommendation for a particular tool, which is offtopic on SO.

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask somewhere else, then.

Answer (score 0):

These two commands on Linux enough to replace domain in Firefox:

```
sqlite3 places.sqlite "DELETE FROM moz_origins WHERE host = 'old.domain.tld';"

sqlite3 places.sqlite "UPDATE moz_places 
                       SET url=REPLACE(moz_places.url, 'old.domain.tld', 'new.domain.tld')   
                       WHERE moz_places.url 
                       LIKE '%old.domain.tld%'"
```

where `places.sqlite` is a file in Firefox profile folder and `sqlite3` is command line took can be installed by `apt install sqlite3`